# Changing the background color of cards

Tags: oracle-apex

I currently have a card region in Oracle APEX 20.2 and I would like for certain cards to have a border color different from the rest.  Ideally, I would be able to define the border color of each card in the card region's source table.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you source a classic report region from SQL using the cards report template, you can define a 'card_color' column that could feed pre-defined classes such as 'u-color-15'.

Combined with the 'Animation - color fill' template selection, this will apply the colour on hover.

If you want to sustain this colour, one option is to add a class to each relevant card using the 'card_modifier' column.

Then add this CSS to your page, where titles-r is my static region ID, and pending is my card modifier value.

```
#tiles-r .pending .t-Card a{background-color: #ebf6fb;}
```

This CSS could be added to your page from generated from SQL, if necessary.

This may all depend on the APEX version you have.

Comment: unfortunately I need the ability to add action buttons to my cards as well and I'm not sure how I would implement that with the classic report

Comment: I am also afraid that the code you provided didn't work with APEX 20.2

Comment: That was written in 20.2, and retested in 22.1. The column aliases available for use a re documented here https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut16/card-templates, but I'm not sure action buttons are available

Answer (score 0):

Go to Card Region--> Attributes--> Card Classes -->paste below value

```
&CARD_COLOR!ATTR.
```

primary key column 1- leave as select

In select query, you can pass "card_color" as below

```
  case when deptno = 10 then
       'u-color-2'
   when deptno = 20 then
       'u-color-3'
   when deptno = 30 then
       'u-color-4'
   when deptno = 40 then
       'u-color-5'
   end card_color
```

check color code values from https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/color-and-status-modifiers

Comment: Im using version 20.2 and I don't see a "Card Classes" field in my card region attributes.  After using the available CSS Classes fields to reference CARD_COLOR, none of my options color the entire background and don't work at all with the border options, which would be ideal in my case